# Is there a way to check the roles of users that are currently not logged in?

Tags: java, spring-security

In my project, I send scheduled mails to all registered users. Up to now, there were no restrictions, so I just got all the Users from the database and sent the mails without any security checks. Now, I have to make sure, that only users with a certain role receive those mails.

The only thing I found so far are several ways to check the roles of the currently logged in user. But I need to check the roles of a whole list of users, that are currently not logged in.

I can't figure out how to access these roles. I don't even know if this can be done with spring security at all. So, does anyone know about this kind of problem?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you did not understand what the 'role' means for a user. Usually the role is implemented in the database part of the application. You may have the `User` table with attributes `(id, name, sname, ...., role)` (1st case) or you may have it as a separate table ex 'Roles' with attributes `(id, name, desc)` and then have a `FK` in your `User` table that will link to the `Roles` table (2nd case).

So, when you want to send an email to all those with `role = admin` then you do it like this:

```
sql = "select * from users where role = 'admin'"; //First case

sql = "select * from users , roles where users.role_id = roles.id and roles.desc = 'admin' "; //second case
```

As you have guessed the implementation of this, has nothing to do with spring or whatever security...